# Is $\inf S=\lim \inf_{n \to \infty}s_n=1 ?$ Yes/No

Tags: real-analysis

Is the following statement true/false ?

> let $p_n$  denote  the $n-$th prime  number, when we  enumerate  the prime numbers in  the increasing order.For  exampe  ,$p_1=2 ,p_2 =3 , p_3=5 $ and  so on.Let  $S= \{s_n=p_{n+1}-p_n| n \in \mathbb{N} , n \geq 1  \}$.Then  $\lim \inf_{n \to \infty} s_n \ge 2$

**My attempt** : I think this statement  is false because $\lim \inf_{n \to \infty}s_n=1$

Here $p_1 =2 , p_2=3, p_3=5 ,p_4 =7 ,p_5=11 , p_6=13$

$\implies  S_1=p_2-p_1=3-2=1$

$S_2=p_3-p_2=5-3=2$

$S_3=p_4-p_3 =7-5=2$

$S_4=p_5-p_4=11-7=4$

.....

Therefore $S=\{1,2,2,4,2,....\}$

$\sup S =\infty$ and $\inf S=1$

I think $\inf S=\lim \inf_{n \to \infty}s_n=1$

Am i right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not right.

Formally for a sequence $(a_n)_n$ we have:$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n\text{ where }b_n=\inf\{b_k\mid k\geq n\}$$

Here $(b_n)_n$ is an increasing sequence so that: $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n\geq b_n\text{ for every }n$$

Consequently for every fixed positive integer $n$ the liminf does not depend on the values $a_1,\dots,a_n$.

You can also think of the liminf as the smallest value such that a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ exists that converges to it provided that $(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence.